# Replacement for an old FD-M760 front derailleur

Tags: derailleur, front

I've got a bent FD-M760 front derailleur. I'm wondering what the best replacement would be?

Comment: An un-bent one perhaps ?

Answer (score 2):

Shimano used the same actuation ratio for all rear derailleurs up 9 speed on mountain bikes, and I'm pretty sure the same holds for front derailleurs. That means you can use any  8 or 9 speed front derailleur to replace a 9 speed M760.

I'd go with a FD-M4000 Alivio or FD-M3000 Acera if you want a new unit. Older 9 speed derailleurs will work if you can find one in good condition.

Note you'll need to match your mounting type: braze-on vs clamp-on; and top of bottom pull. If clamp on you'll need to know your down tube diameter and may need an adapter.

Comment: You do need to pay attention to up vs down pull, and tube angle.

Comment: I would like to keep the XT level, I understand that going to 10 speed (T8000) would work on the 9 with careful adjustment, but what happens with the 11?

Comment: @dolphin bear in mind that M/T 8000 is *way* better than M670, and an Alivio or Deore front derailleur will work just as well.

Comment: Realistically the FD's groupset doesn't matter much at all.  There's less difference between the grades because they all do exactly the same job, and brute force is the only way to move a chain under tension.